# How can I access an object property named as a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I Know that there are lots of questions like this here on Stack, but none of then helped me;
The problem I'm trying to solve is:

Say I have an (dynamic) object:

```
var car = {
        color: 'red',
        doors: 2,
        engine: {
            fuel: 'diesel',
            model: '6 inline'
        },
        driver: {
            name: {
                first: 'John',
                last: 'Meier',
            },
            age: 30
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is: Have a string inside a variable like `var prop = "driver.name.first"` and use it for example as

```
var driverName = getProp('driver.name.first');
var engineModel = getProp('engine.model');

function getProp(prop){
    return car[prop];
}
```

PS: It's a dynamic object which can even be a totally different one, so that's I can't use like `var driverName = car[driver][name][first]` or `var driverName = car.driver.name.first`

Comment: how do you know what string to pass to the `getProp` function? and if you know the string to pass why cant you query the object directly?

Comment: It does not matter if it is dynamic or not. If you know which string to pass to the function, you know how to call it directly

Comment: @Weedoze I don't know what the path will be because this will be called from a function...

Comment: I've chosen to use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22129960/5463835) solution from the duplicate answer because of [K.I.S.S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)